# Bad thing to be a type specifier: number

Tags: common-lisp, type-declaration

`number` is a type specifier: [CLtl2 4.1 Type Specifier Symbols](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node45.html#SECTION00810000000000000000)

However, I can't use it with `declaim`:

```
(defparameter *foo* 0)
(declaim (type (number) *FOO*))
```

=>

```
bad thing to be a type specifier: (NUMBER)
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

`(typep *FOO* 'number)` is T.

So I must use `(or integer float)` ?

What am I missing?

thanks

SBCL1.4.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CLtL2 is not authoritative for Common Lisp. CLtL2 describes a language prior to the ANSI standardization.

Use the Common Lisp HyperSpec, which is derived from the ANSI CL standard: [CLHS 4.2.3 Type Specifiers](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/04_bc.htm).

[NUMBER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_number.htm#number) is an [atomic type specifier](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_a.htm#atomic_type_specifier).

Type specifiers which can be written as a list **with** subsidiary type information are called *compound type specifier* and some are *compound-only type specifiers*.

The glossary says:

> atomic type specifier n. a type specifier that is atomic. For every atomic type specifier, x, there is an equivalent compound type specifier with no arguments supplied, (x).

**This would indicate that `(number)` is a valid type specifier. Some implementations accept it: LispWorks, ABCL, GCL, ...**

Since the glossary is part of the standard, this might be a bug and/or an omission in SBCL, CLISP, Clozure CL, ...

Then this usage of type specifiers is legal:

```
(declaim (type number *FOO*))
(declaim (type (number) *FOO*))

(typep *FOO* 'number)
(typep *FOO* '(number))
```

Comment: Answer on the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1851437 That's an error: `(typep 3 '(number))`.

Comment: @Ehvince: but the ANSI CL standard clearly says that it is not an error.

Comment: @Ehvince: the standard says it's not an error as Rainer says.  So if SBCL does not accept it, then SBCL is not conforming to the standard.

Answer (score 4):

While [symbol](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm)
[`number`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_number.htm) *is* a
[type specifier](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/04_bc.htm),
[list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm) `(number)` is *not*.

Please use

```lisp
(declaim (type number *FOO*))
```

instead.

**PS1**. I recommend that you use CLHS rather than CLtL2 as a reference.
The former is based on the official ANSI CL standard, while the latter is obsolete.

**PS2**. Note that `number` is `(or real complex)` rather than `(or integer float)`.